# Problem about weak* convergence.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $1 \leq p \leq \infty.$ Consider the sequence $(f_n)$ in $(\ell_p)'$ defined by $f_n(x_1, x_2, x_3,\dots) = x_n.$

(a) If $p < \infty,$ show that $(f_n)$ is weak* convergence, but it does not converge strongly.

(b) If $p = \infty,$ show that $(f_n)$ is bounded but it has no weak* subsequence convergence.

My efforts:

Item (a): Let $x = (x_n) \in \ell_p,$ i.e, $x_n \to 0.$ Therefore $f_n(x) = x_n \to 0, \forall x.$ This follows that $(f_n)$ is weak* convergence to $f \equiv 0.$ But $(f_n)$ is not convergence strongly, why?

Item (b): I hasn't idea.

Can anyone give me an idea?

Comment: Use the fact that $\ell_p'=\ell_{p'}$ to calculate $||f_n-f_m||$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $\|f_n\| \leq 1$ Since $f_n(e_n)=1$ it follows that $\|f_n\|=1$ for all $n$ Hence, $f_n$ does not tend to $0$ strongly. [If it converges is has to converge to $0$ by weak* convergence].

When $p=\infty$ and $n_1<n_2<...$  let $x_{n_k}=1$ for $k$ even, $x_{n_k}=-1$ for $k$ odd and $x_i=0$ when $i$ is not of the form $n_k$. Then $(f_{n_k} (x))$ does not converge.